# Unable to shrink logical drive in Window 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a primary partition C: and a logical drive E: on my Win 7 machine. I want to shrink the logical drive (E:) and create one more partition. I tried using the in built Disk Management Tool but volume shrink does not happen as the available disk space is only 4 MB as per the shrink tool. But actually there is 107 GB free space on it. I have tried de-fragmenting but it gives the same result. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try using Easus Partition Manager Free version and post an image of list of drives that you get.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily using [GParted](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php). It is a very advanced tool for partitioning hard drives and will of course suit your need specified.

How to boot from that USB/CD/DVD can be found [here](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=gparted-live-manual#gparted-live-booting-from-removable-media).

After you have booted, select GParted Default from the boot screen.

GParted will now run after a short while. When it does, it will scan all your hard drives on your computer and provide you with a list of your partitions. Note that all your partitions will not be specified like in Windows. In Windows you have drive letters(example: E: F: G:), here you will have the likes of sda1, sda2, sda3, etc. Here, the *sda* means your first hard drive, if you a second or even a third hard drive, they will be specified as sdb and sdc respectively. sda1 means first partition on your first hard drive, sda2 means second partition on your first hard drive, sda3 means your third partition on your first hard drive, and so on.

For resizing you will need to know which partition to shrink. You can easily find that out if you have a Label for your E: drive, and the size of the drive, i.e 107 GB can also be used to figure that out.

From here on it is very simple. Right click on the partition you want to shrink. Click on Resize, then put the size you want to make it in the New Size field, press Tab button, then click on Resize/Move. And it should be done in a bit.

To make a new partition, you will now see some 'unallocated' space. Right click on that, select New, fill in the details of the size, Label you want it to have, etc. But do notice the File System. Select ntfs as your filesystem. Then click Add.

You should now exit from that GParted live session, to do that just double click on Exit from the Desktop.

After you boot into Windows, you should see a new partition.